# How to connect 2 computers on diffrent networks using python sockets

Tags: python, python-sockets

I'm trying to connect 2 different computers that on different networks,
but I got an error:

> TimeoutError: [Errno 110] Connection timed out

And sometimes I got this error:

> OSError: [Errno 113] No route to host

I wrote the `server.py` script and started it on the first pc and `client.py` on the second one.

`server.py`

```py
import socket
server_socket = socket.socket()
server_socket.bind(("127.0.0.1", 80))
server_socket.listen(1)
(client_socket, client_address) = server_socket.accept()
print ("client_connected [" + client_address[0] + "]")
client_command = client_socket.recv(1024).decode()
print(client_command.encode())
```

`client.py`

```py
import socket
client_socket = socket.socket()
client_socket.connect(("server_public_ip_here", 8820))
client_command = input("command: ")
client_socket.send(client_command.encode())
data = client_socket.recv(1024).decode()
print("server: " + data)
```

I expect to get a connections between the computers but keep getting a `TimeoutError` or `OSError`

Comment: It looks like you are listening on port 80 but trying to connect to port 8820.

Comment: Also, you're binding to 127.0.0.1 and connecting to a different IP.

Answer (score 1):

if you are on two separate computers you should bind to `0.0.0.0` (to listen to all network connections) or to the server's IP for connections on that IP, and not `127.0.0.1` (`localhost`). Works if client and server are both in the same machine. Also you should use the same port on client and server.

I test it and it worked:

server.py

```
import socket
server_socket = socket.socket()
server_socket.bind(("0.0.0.0", 8000))
server_socket.listen(1)
(client_socket, client_address) = server_socket.accept()
print ("client_connected [" + client_address[0] + "]")
client_command = client_socket.recv(1024).decode()
print(client_command.encode())
```

client.py

```
import socket
client_socket = socket.socket()
client_socket.connect(("127.0.0.1", 8000)) #or enter ip of server
client_command = input("command: ")
client_socket.send(client_command.encode())
data = client_socket.recv(1024).decode()
print("server: " + data)
```

Comment: A few notes:
1. Avoid using 8000 as a port or any that start with 80 for that matter, many other server applications use them.
2. Make sure you have set your firewall policies correctly for TCP traffic on the port you are using for both machines.